# Using specific branch in Intellij for displayed changes

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I'm using Intellij with python (would be able to use Pycharm as well) and git. I find it's really useful to have a different color for files that I change, have indicators on the side for lines that I changed, etc.

I can't figure out whether you can, instead of using HEAD as your branch for displaying changed things, use a different branch/revision/commit. Once I commit, all the information about changes is gone from the interface. While I might care about what I changed since the last commit, it's more often the case that I'd like to compare with respect to the origin branch that I'm branching from.

Do you know whether that's possible, or have you used it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful "[Compare with branch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/comparing-file-versions.html)"

So you need to right-click on a file -> Git | Compare with Branch and choose the desired branch.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's useful, but doesn't work for the rest of the elements of the interface (indications in each line of what changed, different colors for changed files in the Structure view and the tabs, etc.)